# Select multiple tag values using the xsl select attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

i'm using the following XML block of code :

```
 <w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
       <w:tcW w:w="7300" />
       <w:gridSpan w:val="3" />
       <w:tcBorders>
          <w:top w:val="nil" />
          <w:left w:val="nil" />
          <w:bottom w:val="nil" />
          <w:right w:val="nil" />
       </w:tcBorders>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p>
       <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
             <w:sz w:val="20" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>TEST 1</w:t>
       </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
       <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
             <w:sz w:val="20" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>TEST 2</w:t>
       </w:r>
    </w:p>
 </w:tc>
```

Right now, the following line just returns the value TEST 1

```
<xsl:variable name="runContents" select="substring-after(substring-before($cellData, '</w:t>'),'<w:t>')"/>
```

How is it possible to select all the <w:t> values at once. If possible with a carriage return between.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems you misunderstand how XSLT works. It operates on the XML tree, after it has been parsed. There are no tags in this tree. There is no string equal to  `<w:t>`. In addition, if your attempt does not produce an error due to the unescaped `<` characters, then you are not using a conforming processor.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with XSLT-2.0 or above:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/w:c/w:p/w:r/w:t" separator="&#xa;" />
```

or shorter, respectively, with

```
<xsl:value-of select="//w:t" separator="&#xa;" />
```

The output is

```
TEST 1
TEST 2
```

Instead of using `xsl:value-of` to output the values, you can select all of them with an `xsl:variable`. But for output, you'd have to use the approach above.

---

If you have only XSLT-1.0 available, you'd have to put it in a `for-each` loop to output all of the values:

```
<xsl:variable name="elemName" select="/w:c/w:p/w:r/w:t" />
<xsl:for-each select="$elemName">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output is the same.

Comment: thanks, it seems to be what i'm looking for. However i have a "Prefix 'w' is not defined." error when using the v1 version. I've just tried to shorten a bit the select attribute by using select="//w:t" but the error still appears. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes. It seems that you haven't defined the `prefix:namespace` relation in your code. This means that you have to assign a namespace to your prefix `w`. Its namespace string has to be the same in your XML as well as your XSLT. The prefix, on the other hand, may vary. Usually, the XML defines such a namespace, and the XSLT follows this. Look for a (default) namespace defined by `xmlns=...`.